# Имя сервера и номер порта

Tags: сервер, порты

Думаю вопрос понятен. Как можно это узнать?

(Введите имя вашего сервера и номер порта (их можно узнать у вашего системного администратора) в виде <имя сервера>:<номер порта>. )

Comment: вопрос понятен, а почему он к нам, а не к "вашему системному администратору"? ))

Comment: Нету системного администратора :((

Comment: Найми!....

Comment: могу взяться за $200 ))

Comment: Вопрос как раз и не понятен. Кто или что это Вам выдало? Поясните.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего требуется имя вашего компьютера, это и будет имя "сервера", а вот  с портом проблема, какая именно программа спрашивает об этом? или порт можно задать любой? в принципе можете выбрать какой нибудь свободной порт - заисключением уже занятых (8080,443,25,8081) проверить порт на "открытость" можно тут [2ip.ru](http://2ip.ru/check-port/)

Answer (score 1):

2ip.ru не всегда даст результат, порт то может нужен внутри сети, а снаружи может быть закрыт. Лучьше возьмите любой сканер сети, и сделайте сканирование всех портов из локальной сети.